# What is the max message size in vline person.publishMessage()?

Tags: vline

I am sending a message via publishMessage() and see this:

[131031 00:25:32.79] [vline.cometdTransport] BAD_PARAM ('Message size exceeds limit')

What is the max? Is this actually P2P? is there a way to determine when things are relayed or not?

When messages are cached via person.postMessage(), are they cached on the server or locally? If on the server are they readable by vLine?

Answer (score 0):

The current maximum size limit for `publishMessage` or `postMessage` is 16KB per message.

Currently these APIs are not P2P, so they always go through our servers. Messages sent with `postMessage` are stored in our database so that your message history is consistent across all your sessions. These messages are not encrypted at rest so that we can provide search across your message history.

We intend to add the WebRTC data channel as an alternate backed to the `publishMessage` API; this will be invisible to users of the API. Note that even when we release that functionality you may still end up using the current method, which provides compatibility with browsers that don't support WebRTC.